# How do I find the minimal upper bound of flow that can pass for each edges in this graph?

Tags: linear-programming, network-flow

What is in red is the supply/demand. If it's 0 that means that the node is just there for transfering the flow. If it's negative this means that it's the demand and if it's positive then it's the supply.

Brackets in black on edges are the capacity limit. If there is no [ ] on an edge this simply mean that there is no limit. Otherwise, the numbers on the edges are the cost per unit of transfer.

I'm asked for each edge to find the lowest upper bound of flow that can pass through it. However, I'm not sure how to do this? For the node 1 I can put 10 units on each of its edges. Is this the lowest upper bound? How do I figure this out?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_i$ be the supply or demand at node $i \in N$.  For each arc $(i,j)\in A$, introduce a nonnegative flow variable $x_{i,j}$ (some with upper bounds).  For each node $i\in N$, impose linear flow-balance constraints:
$$\sum_{(i,j)\in A} x_{i,j} - \sum_{(j,i)\in A} x_{j,i} = b_i \quad \text{for $i\in N$}$$
For each arc $(i,j)$, maximize $x_{i,j}$.  The maximum values turn out to be:
\begin{matrix}
i & j & \max \\
\hline
1 &2 &10 \\ 
1 &3 &20 \\
1 &4 &20 \\
2 &5 &30 \\
3 &2 &25 \\
3 &4 &30 \\
4 &5 &30 \\ 
\end{matrix}

Comment: Does this mean that $x_{1,2} + x_{1,3} + x_{1,4} - 0 = 20$. The $0$ comes from the fact that we have no edge entering the node 1.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct constraint for node $i=1$.

Comment: Ok, but I have to determine for each edge what the upper bound is. Is the upper bound for $x_{1,2}$ $20$ or $20 - x_{1,3} + x_{1,4}$?

Comment: For each arc, solve the linear program to maximize $x_{i,j}$.  The resulting value is the least upper bound.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure how to understand this. for $x_{1,2}$ is the maximum value 10? If not could you give me an example of maximizing $x_{i,j}$ by solving the linear program for the node 1?

Comment: edge x1,2 not node 1. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @WindBreeze did you see my updated answer?

Comment: Are these also the smallest upper bound possible for each edges? Because I'm asked to find the smallest upper bound possible and here we're maximizing.

Comment: maximum = least upper bound

Comment: Ok thanks. Thank you for being patient with me.